# php mysql + create profile page

Tags: php, mysql

hey i am new here any one can help me with this chunk of code in php and mysql 
 i know that this is a little mistake but i could not know where is the error and thank you.
 this is the code :

//index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search for a user</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Search for a user below:</h2><br /><br />
<form action="profileprocess.php" method="get">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  value="View Profile" /></td>
    </tr>


  </table>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

// profileprocess.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $username; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>s profile</title>

</head>
<body>
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['username'])){

    $username = $_GET['username']; 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("could not connect t the server");
    mysql_select_db("users") or die("this database was not found");
    $userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die("the query could be fale please try again");
    if(mysql_num_rows($userquery) != 1){
        die("that username could not be found!");
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
       $firstname = $row['firstname'];
       $lastname = $row['lastname'];
       $email = $row['email'];
       $dbusername = $row['username'];
       $activated = $row['activated'];
       $access = $row['access'];
       }
       if($username != $dbusername){
         die ("there has been a fatal error please try again. ");
       }
       if($activated == 0){
        $active = "this account has not been activated";
       }else{
          $active = "ths  account has been activated";
       }

       if($access == 0){
         $admin = "this user is not administrator";
       }else{
         $admin = "this user is  an administrator";
       }
?>
<h2><?php echo $username; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>s profile</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>firstname:</td><td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lastname:</td><td><?php echo $lastname; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>email:</td><td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>username:</td><td><?php echo $dbusername; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>activated:</td><td><?php echo $active; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>access:</td><td><?php echo $admin; ?></td>
</tr>

</table>


<?php      
 }else die("You need  to specify a username!");


?>

</body>
</html>
```

//// any help????

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions, as they're deprecated : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php . Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: what is the error you got? that helps a alot put in the question..

Comment: You think people will actually try to run the code? Is it that hard to post the error you get too?

Comment: You seem to be using undefined variables in your title tag. The PHP that does the database lookup should come before any HTML.

Comment: the error is that the result always display "You need  to specify a username!" even if i enter an exist username

Comment: N.B sorry but this is my first time here so be Patient with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just run this code on my XAMPP server and it seems to work fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search for a user</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Search for a user below:</h2><br /><br />
<form action="" method="get">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  value="View Profile" /></td>
    </tr>


  </table>


</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
 if($_GET['username'] != ''){
     echo $_GET['username'];

 } else 
 die('doesnt work'); ?>
```

Comment: i tried this code that you wrote but it give me an error   "Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\profiletest.php on line 24" and display message "doesnt work"  but after i enter a value it display the value

Comment: Exactly so when you submit a text via the inputbox it is working properly. Now just import all your mysql queries in the if tag of php. 

I have put it in 1 single page. just split it into 2 pages that you want.

Comment: it work fine it display the "$_GET USERNAME" BUT NOT ALL THE FIELDS THAT MATCH THIS USERNAME TO BE ABLE TO CREATE A PROFILE PAGE IF YOU UNDERSTAND ME  THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

One problem i definitely see is that you have used echo at the start of the page and the query is not running. That is going to throw up errors.

Also, please tell us what the errors are, so that we can try and help you better.

Comment: THE ERROR THAT I get IS THAT IT DISPLAY THE ERROR MESSAGE "YOU NEED TO SPECIFY A USERNAME"  THAT MEAN THE CODE THROW AN ERROR FROM THE FIRST LINE "if(isset($_GET['username'])){" "ELSE{echo"YOU NEED TO SPECIFY A USERNAME" }"

Comment: Hello,
To easily solve this problem try changing your code to
`code`
if($_GET['username'] !='') on your first line. This should fix it.